# Android Rubik's Cube Kociemba optimal solver memory shortage

Tags: android, memory-management, rubiks-cube

I'd like to ask for some help about the following problem I have.

I'd like to create an application that solves the Rubik's cube with an optimal solution. I downloaded the following library, whitch supposedly does just that using the Kociemba's Algorithm.

http://kociemba.org/twophase.jar

Apparently it can solve the cube in under 0.5 sec, but in my app it never returned the solution due to memory problems. I know it works, I tested it with wrong inputs and it returns the documented error codes.

I call it in my onCreate method like this:

```
resultTxt = Search.solution(data, 21, 10, true);
```

resultTxt is a String variable and it should contain the solution.

It quickly eats up the memory.

I tried it with IntentService without success. By this I mean it didn't really changed anything.

As i didn't find any evidence of anyone using this library in any android application, I thought I would ask someone who is more experienced than me.

Is there any way I could make this work on Android, or is this as impossible as I thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a bit late, but I was also facing this issue quite recently when I was working on a Rubik's-Cube-solving-robot using an Android-Smartphone for scanning the cube and computing the solution, so I'll put here what I have found out.

---

**What is the problem?**

Let's start off by discussing where the problem causing that performance issue actually is located.

The reason for that being so slow is the class `CoordCube`, which looks (very simplified) like this:

```
class CoordCube {
    short[] pruneTables;

    static {
        /* compute and save ~50MB data in `pruneTables` */
    }
}
```

Basically what it does, is to load a pretty big amount of data into lookup-tables which are required for a fast solving procedure. This loading is automatically executed by the `JVM` once this class is first instantiated. That happens on `line 159` in `Search.solution()`:

```
/* simplified code of solution() */
if (cube.isValid()) {
    CoordCube c = new CoordCube(); // pruning tables will be loaded on this line
```

That is also the reason why this method executes in negligible time as long as the passed cube is invalid, since it never gets to load the tables.

---

**Possible Solutions:**

Now that we have identified where the problem is located, let's focus on how to solve it.

I have come up with 3 different approaches, where the first one is probably the easiest (but also the slowest execution wise ...) and is also used in my App. The other two are just ideas on how to improve the performance even more.

**Approach 1:**

The first and most simple approach is to just manually preload the lookup tables in a kind of `LoadingActivity` with a `ProgressBar` showing our current progress. For that we first want to be able to manually control exactly when which tables are loaded (when the class is first instantiated is not precise enough), like this:

```
loadTable1() {
     /* load pruning table number 1 */
}
```

For that I have written some simple utility [here](https://gist.github.com/efrantar-tgm/181886d6c678fb9de31b) (code is too long to paste). Make sure to check out my instructions there on how to properly import that code in your App.

Also we will probably want to do the loading in the background, namely in an `AsyncTask`. This is how I have done it in my application (`PruneTableLoader` is included in the previous link):

```
private class LoadPruningTablesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private PruneTableLoader tableLoader = new PruneTableLoader();

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        /* load all tables if they are not already in RAM */
        while (!tableLoader.loadingFinished()) { // while tables are left to load
            tableLoader.loadNext(); // load next pruning table
            publishProgress(); // increment `ProgressBar` by one
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        /* increment `ProgressBar` by 1 */
    }
}
```

When using my `PruneTableLoader`, the loading of all tables needs about `40s` on my `Samsung Galaxy S3` with `250 MB RAM free`. (in contrast it needs `well over 2min` when loading them automatically and in addition often results in a crash ...)

That may still sound quite slow considering it needs `< 1s` on PC, but at least you must only do that once, since Android caches the static-variables and you so don't have to load them on every startup of your App.

**Approach 2: (untested)**

I assume it would be faster to save the pruning tables in a `file` or a `database` and load them from there instead of always recomputing them. I have not yet tested that though and it will probably require quite some work getting the saving and loading to work properly. (also maybe it's not even faster because of access times)

**Approach 3: (untested)**

Well, the hardest and also by decades most work expensive solution would be, to simply rewrite the whole algorithm in `C` or `C++` and invoke it in the App via `JNI`. (*Herbert Kociemba* has not published his `C-sourcecode` yet as far as I know ...)

This is going to be the performance wise fastest solution for sure. (also for the solving procedure itself)

---

All in all **approach 1** is probably the effort/benefit-wise best approach for the beginning (and also was for me), so I would recommend you to go with that, in case the loading time is not such a huge issue for your Application.

I'm not completely satisfied with the performance of that myself though, so I may try out **approach 2** and maybe even **approach 3** some time in the future. In case I do that, I will update this post with my results then.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I did try stroring the tables with little success. Your suggestion however seems like would have helped me greatly while developing my app. Fortunatelly i found another way to optimally solve a 3 by 3 cube on android. It takes maybe about 2-3 sec, give or take, to solve the cube with about 23 moves. You can check it out if you search rubik's cube fridrich solver on play.